# Sliding Window operations across groups in Spark DataFrame with multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` as below:

```
scala> Seq(("2020-05-21","x",1),("2020-05-21","y",2),("2020-05-22","x",3),("2020-05-22","y",4),("2020-05-23","x",5), ("2020-05-23","y",6)).toDF("dt","A","B")
+----------+---+---+
|        dt|  A|  B|
+----------+---+---+
|2020-05-21|  x|  1|
|2020-05-21|  y|  2|
|2020-05-22|  x|  3|
|2020-05-22|  y|  4|
|2020-05-23|  x|  5|
|2020-05-23|  y|  6|
+----------+---+---+
```

I am trying to find, for the past 2 days(including current day) the sum of B grouped by A.

In other words: group by A & dt(only current & previous dt) find moving sum of B.

Expected Output:

```
+----------+---+---+----+
|        dt|  A|  B| sum|
+----------+---+---+----+
|2020-05-21|  x|  1|   1|
|2020-05-21|  y|  2|   2|
|2020-05-22|  x|  3|   4|  // (1 + 3) (i.e: for dt = May 21 & 22, A = x)
|2020-05-22|  y|  4|   6|  // (4 + 2) (i.e: for dt = May 21 & 22, A = y)
|2020-05-23|  x|  5|   8|  // (5 + 3) (i.e: for dt = May 22 & 23, A = x)
|2020-05-23|  y|  6|  10|  // (6 + 4) (i.e: for dt = May 22 & 23, A = y)
+----------+---+---+----+
```

Tried Window functions with `.rowsBetween()` like:

```
res0.withColumn("sum", sum($"B").over(Window.partitionBy($"dt",$"A").rowsBetween(-1,0)))
```

but this approach will not work as grouping both dt & A will result in only 1 row per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val dtWindow = Window.partitionBy("dt","A").orderBy("dt")
val aWindow = Window.partitionBy("A").orderBy("dt").rangeBetween(lit(-1),currentRow())
df.withColumn("dt",col("dt").cast("date")).withColumn("sum",sum($"B").over(dtWindow)).withColumn("sum",sum("sum").over(aWindow)).orderBy("dt","A").show

+----------+---+---+---+
|        dt|  A|  B|sum|
+----------+---+---+---+
|2020-05-21|  x|  1|  1|
|2020-05-21|  y|  2|  2|
|2020-05-22|  x|  3|  4|
|2020-05-22|  y|  4|  6|
|2020-05-23|  x|  5|  8|
|2020-05-23|  y|  6| 10|
+----------+---+---+---+
```

Points to note:

- Convert 'dt' to Date type for correct type comparison while using
  rangeBetween.
- Use rangeBetween instead of rowsBetween to get sum of    today and
  yesterday. If data for yesterday is not available your sum    will be
  only of todays data. If you use rowsBetween then the sum will    be
  of today and the day immediate lower than today in the data.

Comment: the solution is partly correct. Using a second window is the correct approach. But to calculate previous date's sum `.rowsBetween()` will lead to wrong calculation if there is a missing date. Here is an example data for this scenario: `Seq(("2020-05-19","x",3),("2020-05-21","x",1),("2020-05-21","y",2),("2020-05-22","x",3),("2020-05-22","y",4),("2020-05-23","x",5), ("2020-05-23","y",6)).toDF("dt","A","B")`

Comment: In the above example `dt = 2020-05-20` is missing. `sum` value for `dt = 2020-05-21` and `A = x` in your code will be: `4`, as it includes `dt = 2020-05-19`'s B value too. But the correct answer is `1`

Comment: @vdep thats correct, updated the answer. Instead of rowsBetween, use rangeBetween with literals.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
val windowFn = Window.partitionBy($"A").orderBy($"dt".asc)
   newDF.withColumn("dummy", lag($"B",1,0).over(windowFn)).withColumn("sum", $"dummy" + $"B").drop($"dummy").orderBy($"dt".asc).show


+----------+---+---+---+
|        dt|  A|  B|sum|
+----------+---+---+---+
|2020-05-21|  x|  1|  1|
|2020-05-21|  y|  2|  2|
|2020-05-22|  x|  3|  4|
|2020-05-22|  y|  4|  6|
|2020-05-23|  x|  5|  8|
|2020-05-23|  y|  6| 10|
+----------+---+---+---+
```

If any tricky part in your questions , please highlight in bold. that will help to find quickly